# Quickest way to install Release build on device?

Tags: ios, xcode, build, installation, release

What is the easiest/quickest way make Xcode install a Release build of my app onto a device? Right now I create an ipa and then manually install it. Can I create a new scheme to do it? Also, I would prefer that the app is just installed onto the device - without having to run it.

Thanks

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should be able to go in to your Edit Schemes preference pane. You can change your Build Configuration to Release there. I would suggest creating a duplicate scheme in which you can build Release builds.

Comment: This answer is correct. Get ready to run on your device like you normally would. Just hold Option and click Run. The scheme editor opens on the way to running. Switch the configuration to Release and click the Run button. Badda bing badda boom! But if you're going to do a lot of this sort of thing, do make a second scheme, because you cannot debug a release build and you can confuse yourself when you build and run and your breakpoints don't work because you left it in Release configuration instead of Debug configuration.

Comment: i am getting an error "module not found" for all my modules, and this is happening when i am changing, debug schema to release. Archive and other things are running without any issue but unable to test the release version using schema.  (Edit: I am trying to run the app on simulator)

Comment: `Menu bar` > `Product` > `Scheme` > `Edit scheme`

Answer (score 13):

@atreat's answer might be a better idea in general, but I'm not at my Mac to test right now...

I just hit the Profile button/menu in Xcode. That builds the Release configuration by default, puts it on the device, and launches Instruments. Just quit or ignore Instruments and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, neat little trick! Can confirm that it still works with Xcode 10

Comment: Doesn't this depend on your scheme and what you have set to build when you profile?

Answer (score 1):

> Also, I would prefer that the app is just installed onto the device - without having to run it.

Then build and run and hit Stop. Now it's installed.

Comment: You can also switch the 'Launch' option in the Edit Scheme -> Run pane from 'Automatically' to 'Wait for executable to be launched' to prevent the app from launching when 'Run' is pressed in Xcode.

Comment: @atreat Actually everything here is completely outdated, since the Simulator now permits side-loading of apps.