# Developing iOS for enterprise as individual Developer

Tags: ios

Heyo Guys
I got a question about the deployment of my App. I am currently doing contracting for a small to medium size business. The app is (as the title suggests) developped for iOS. 
The app should be for internal use only so putting it on the app store would not be a good idea. 
I have read about the enterprise developer program which sounds pretty much like the thing I need except for 2 aspects :
1. 299 per year
2. Enterprise apps are intended for really big companies.

Is there any other way to distribute the app to the 10+ people working at the business I am currently working for ?

Thanks for your advice

**EDIT** : Thanks for all your answers. I have plans to then further distribute the app to other companies (the app is for driving schools) so that means that there would again be a problem if each of those companies had to buy a licence in order to use my app

Comment: Your client should enroll for an enterprise development program

Comment: `Is there any other way to distribute the app to the 10+ people working at the business I am currently working for ?` If it's really only about 10 people you can get it on their device via Xcode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13925590/quickest-way-to-install-release-build-on-device

Comment: On a per user basis, lets do the math: $299 (ignoring the $99 for a standard license) / 10 = $29/user. That does not seem unreasonable. Or how does the extra $200 compare to development costs? Finally you can always put it in the app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter about the size of the company, If they want an internal application not hosted on the App Store then the Enterprise program is the way to go.

This is something that the client should be paying for though, they could then use a service like Hockey to host their applications for employees.

If the company only needed the app for say 10 devices, they could *technically* just get away with an AdHoc build but there are drawbacks:

- AdHoc builds are intended for testing rather than full scale distribution.
- The devices would have to be registered on the developer portal, this means that if a new device needs adding then *you* would have to add it then re-generate a new provisioning profile.
- You're limited on how many devices you can distribute to.
- <strike>The provisioning profile will expire after 3 months.</strike>
- Provisioning profiles currently expire after a year just like enterprise profiles however [Apple have been known to change this](http://www.engadget.com/2009/11/26/provision-profile-expiration-time-does-it-leave-you-wondering/).

Comment: The provisioning profile expires after 1 year, not 3 months.

Comment: @Kuantan AdHoc provisioning profiles expire after 90 days. Enterprise however will last a whole year.

Comment: Strange... I just created an AdHoc provisioning profile in the member center and it shows an expiry date equal to my developer account expiry date, which is more then 3 months. I found the documentation about enterprise account (indeed 1 year) but not yet about the normal account.

Comment: @Kuantan You're right.. Apple doc's don't specify but it currently is 1 year... I'm about to update my answer with a little more info. Thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

If it's 10 people, you can ask them to hand over their devices and you install using Xcode. For 50 you can make them beta testers, but it is a pain. Testflight will work, but you have to upload a version once a month which they have to download. All of these might be against your license.

It would be by far the best if the company you are working for buys an enterprise license. (YOU can't buy the enterprise license, because the users are not YOUR employees).

Comment: For multiple businesses this strategy would fall apart wouldn't it ?

Comment: Which part would fall apart?

Comment: Well if there are multiple businesses it would be extremely cumbersome to go and get every device and all add them manually

Comment: Indeed you should let the company you work for buy the license. I just wonder which percentage of independent developers use their own enterprise account to service company A, B and C . Is Apple checking and enforcing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can distribute via TestFlight, but those 10 users will eat in to your limit of 25 total Beta testers.

Comment: Testflight user limit has been increased to 1000.

Comment: TestFlight has time limitations.

Comment: I think the test flight limit is 30 days

Comment: 30 days is the correct testflight limit, then you need to re-invite

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly take the target users' device UUIDs and provision your app to be able to run on them. Then, you can create ad-hoc deployments of your app which can be installed directly on the target devices using iTunes, or distribute them using something like Crashlytics.

You can add 100 devices per year as a registered developer.

Comment: There are time limitations. While you can add 100 devices per you will have to delete 100 devices per year prior to developer renewal.